# Celery beat dyanmically changing time peroids

Tags: django, celery

I have implemented celery in my project, and had requirement to add periodic task, so I have researched and found we can use periodic task too using library, but the problem is i want task time to be periodically changing by admin, how can i do that?

Thanks  in advance

Comment: read documentation https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-celery-beat-database-backed-periodic-tasks-with-admin-interface

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`django-celery-beat` for dynamic task scheduling from django admin panel,

Please find below proper documentation for library

https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-beat/